Problem with Visual Studio and XCode build for .NET MAUI development
I've been programming in .NET MAUI for about six months and frequently face compatibility issues between Visual Studio and XCode when developing for iOS. Here are the problems I'm encountering:
I keep getting errors about needing a different version of XCode. For example, when I install XCode 16, Visual Studio stops detecting my Mac, and pairing fails.
Could someone suggest the best versions of Visual Studio and XCode to use for stable .NET MAUI development on iOS? Has anyone else experienced this issue, and how did you resolve it?
Also, if anyone knows of any programming communities on this platform where I can ask similar questions, I'd be grateful for any recommendations.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Everything used to work fine on Visual Studio 17.11.4 and XCode 15.4, but after an automatic update to Visual Studio 17.4.5, I can no longer build my project.
